# Python pymsgbox won't close on Cancel button

Tags: python

Simply trying to allow the user to close/cancel out of app if they change their mind.

I've tried the cancelButton and instead of pymsgbox.prompt, pymsgbox.Confirm, to no avail.

```
while True:
    deviceNumber= pymsgbox.prompt('Change device_number to:', default='Enter device number here.', title='Change text file')

    if deviceNumber not in deviceList:
        pymsgbox.alert("Sorry, wrong device number.")
        continue
    else:
        pymsgbox.alert("Please restart device")
        break
```

I'm stuck in a loop. When I select the cancel button, the app doesn't close. When I click the red X, it won't close either.

Comment: You have to explicitly check for a `None` return value to handle the cancel button.

Comment: I tried:
'pymsgbox.__buttonEvent(None)' but this is throwing errors any which way I try it. Are you able to be more specific @jasonharper ? Thanks

Comment: What was that even supposed to do?  Names starting with underscores are generally internal details that you shouldn't mess with.  What I was suggesting was something like `if deviceNumber is None: break`.